# Difference between values in consecutive rows for unique ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-manipulation

SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to find the difference between consecutive rows based on a common, unique ID.

```
Data:

AccountNumber   ValueDate     CustomerName        Amount           Difference

     1           06/01/2014   Customer Name 1   -3436.184178    
     2           06/03/2014   Customer Name 2   -154.5               -51.5
     2           06/15/2014   Customer Name 2   -103    
     3           06/02/2014   Customer Name 3   -45289.44   
     4           06/20/2014   Customer Name 4   -4907.52             -1116.43
     4           06/25/2014   Customer Name 4   -3791.09             -3791.09
     4           06/30/2014   Customer Name 4   -3302.19
```

The difference column is what I'm trying to generate.
I need to find the difference between consecutive rows ONLY IF:

There is more than 1 row for a particular AccountNumber.

---

I managed to remove the rows with 1 value/AccountNumber [rows 1 and 4 in this case]

I still need to find the difference from [row - row + 1]
I saw a couple of answers on Stack overflow but they don't seem to apply to this scenario.

Comment: You need to dictate what "consecutive rows" means. How does SQL Server know that -154.5 came before -103? (Also, AccountNumber is not unique if it can have the same value in two rows.)

Comment: Tables represent unordered sets.  Hence, there is no such thing as a "consecutive row" unless you explicitly have a column with the ordering -- typically an id or creation date.  Your data has no such column, hence it has no "consecutive row".

Comment: Edited to include ValueDate as a reference point for consecutivity [not sure if that's a word]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY ValueDate) AS RN 
              FROM YourTable)
SELECT a.*,a.Amount - b.Amount AS Diff
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
  AND a.RN = b.RN -1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in a group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY AccountNumber`  then for each unique `AccountNumber` value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the numbering should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Used in a cte you can then self-join using the `ROW_NUMBER()` to offset the join by 1 record, allowing comparison between rows.

In SQL Server 2012 the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions allow for simpler cross-row comparisons.

Comment: Perfect. I replaced the ??? with ValueDate as suggested by Aaron and Gordon and I have the data I need.